# Highcharts Ganttchart (or XRange) group y-Axis elements

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart

I need to group elements on the y-Axis and not sure how to achieve this. It can be with x-range or gantt, with category, grid or treegrid, whichever works best.

Here's an example

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Grouped Categories` plugin:

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    labels: {
        groupedOptions: [{
            rotation: -90,
        }],
    },
    categories: [{
        name: "Fruit",
        categories: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/caj3rwdy/

**Docs:** https://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

Comment: these links are not working

Comment: Hi @Wahab Shah, Updated, thanks!

Comment: thanks. Docs link is working but the Live demo has some script error

Comment: Also updated! :)